# CSS: Overlapping elements with rounded corners

Tags: css

[image]

No problem to get the rounded corners but how can I get them to overlap though so that I can see through?

Current code:

```
nav li{
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px;
   background: #ccc;
   float:left;
   width: 192px;
   text-align:center;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 25px 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you're asking for opacity, or asking how to achieve the look in that image with an overlay, so I'll address both..

**Opacity**

Set this on the classes for the buttons.

```
opacity:0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
```

This will make the boxes 50% transparent, although you can edit how much by editing the two 5's above to any other number.

**Overlay**

Give the classes for the buttons a negative left margin. This will make them look like they do in the image you posted (assuming that's what you want, and not what you already have). Change the -10 to any other number to suit your needs on the spacing of them (trial and error to test the spacing).

```
margin-left: -10px;
```

Comment: Thanks, also I actually tried the negative margins but failed to realise i needed to float them all right instead of left for the overlap to work.